# Watir: set custom profile to watir firefox not working

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir, watir-webdriver

I found many hints to implement custom profile settings to the watir firefox browser, but all don't work.

Setting for private browsing:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.privatebrowsing.dont_prompt_on_enter'] = true
profile['browser.privatebrowsing.autostart'] = true
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

Setting for auto save file:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
profile['browser.download.dir'] = path
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "text/csv"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

Error message:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:80:in `initialize': unknown option: {:profile=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile:0x000000016da348 @model=nil, @native_events=false, @secure_ssl=false, @untrusted_issuer=true, @load_no_focus_lib=false, @additional_prefs={"browser.privatebrowsing.dont_prompt_on_enter"=>true, "browser.privatebrowsing.autostart"=>true}, @extensions={}>} (ArgumentError)
```

Is it possible the customize the settings on firefox? What is wrong?

- Watir Version: 6.0.2
- Selenium Version: 3.0.1
- Browser Version: Firefox 51.0.1
- Browser Driver Version: geckodriver 0.11.1
- OS Version: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 3):

Assign your profile in options.profile

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
profile['browser.download.dir'] = path
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "text/csv"
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new(profile: profile)
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, options: options
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working. Error message: uninitialized constant Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options (NameError)

Comment: Have you require "selenium-webdriver" in your project ?

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings#firefox

Comment: No, i required only watir. I just tested with additionally require "selenium-webdriver", but the same error message occur. If i disable the profile lines the browser will be start without any problem. I think it is not neccessary to include selenium-webdriver if watir is required.

Comment: It's not necessary to require selenium-webdriver if you require watir

Comment: Thanks, but the custom profile setting is still not working.

Comment: @GunnarGläser Yes, I haven't had any success yet here. I am also looking for a solution to this problem.